# In Services.msc which service is used to send mails in SQL Server 2017?

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2017 and I am using some email services. I was not able to find out what service in `Services.msc` is used to send mails. I have to stop that email service and have to find some alternative service which can deliver a mail efficiently without overloading the server.

Can anyone give some suggestions or solutions?

I'm new to this, hope someone can give me some advice.

Comment: The [fine manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/database-mail/database-mail-external-program) covers this. It's not a service.

Comment: The email service is built into SQL server. It is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/database-mail/configure-database-mail?view=sql-server-2017)